# Firebase Firestore query an array of more than 10 elements

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[[image: **enter image description here**][image]

I am trying to query the post-collection with the user settings but the settings is an array of more than 10 elements and nothing is returned. I know the documents did mention the limit of 10 elements, does anyone know a workaround?

```
firebaseApp.collection('posts')
            .where("newTag", "in", mySettings)
            .get()
let array = [];
        posts.forEach((post) => {
            array.push(post.data());
        });

dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.GET_POSTS, payload: array });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround is to perform a query for each item in `mySettings` individually, and merge the results on the client.  Or, split `mySettings` into another collection of arrays that each have 10 or less items, query for each one of those individually, and merge the results on the client.

Comment: How about a Twitter-like application that needs to show tweets from all followed users in the feed? A user might follow several hundred other users, in which case merging the results on the client would cause tons of additional reads.

Comment: I would say this works unless you are trying to do pagination using `limit`

Answer (score 4):

A simple function to chunk the array could solve your problem:

```
const chunkArray = (list: any[], chunk: number): any[][] => {
    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += chunk) {
        result.push(list.slice(i, i + chunk));
    }

    return result;
};

export { chunkArray };
```

Then a for await hack to get the snaps would work as well:

```
  const snaps_collection: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot[] = [];

  for await (const snap of chunks.map(
    async (chunk) =>
      await database
        .collection("collection_name")
        .where("id", "in", chunk)
        .get()
  )) {
    snaps_collection.push(snap);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a wherein [using a chunk of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) of mysettings, each chunk could have a maximum size of 10, then join the results into a single array

Answer (score 1):

This solution using typescript, you can convert this one into your programming language.

Time Complexity: while loop running `length / 10` times.

```
export async function getUsersByIds(ids: [string]) {
    let users = []
    const limit = 10

    while (ids.length) {
        const res = await db
            .collection('users')
            .where('uid', 'in', ids.slice(0, limit))
            .get()
        const _users = res.docs.map((doc) => {
            const _data = doc.data() as UserModel
            _data.docId = doc.id
            return _data
        })

        users.push(..._users)
        ids.splice(0, limit)
    }

    return users
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is more Typescript eslint friendly way(no usage of `any`)

Array chunk method in `ArrayUtils.ts`

```js
export function chunk<M>(array: Array<M>, chunkSize: number) {
  const ans: Array<Array<M>> = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {
    ans[Math.floor(i / chunkSize)] = array.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
  }
  return ans;
}
```

now in `FirebaseUtils.kt`, you can write

```
import { chunk } from "./ArrayUtils";

export async function inQuery<M>(
  docRef: FirebaseFirestore.CollectionReference,
  field: string | FirebaseFirestore.FieldPath,
  values: Array<string>
) {
  const querySnapshots = await Promise.all(
    chunk(values, 10).map((chunkedArray) => {
      return docRef.where(field, "in", chunkedArray).get();
    })
  );
  return querySnapshots
    .flatMap((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs)
    .map((documentData) => documentData.data() as M);
}
```

Few advantages over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73959725/5028085) answer

1. Refactored as proper utility methods for reusability
2. Used `Promise.all` which is parallel and more recommended than `for await` as later is used when we don't have all the promises upfront. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695815/5028085)