# for await of VS Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, for-await

Is there any difference between this:

```js
const promises = await Promise.all(items.map(e => somethingAsync(e)));
for (const res of promises) {
  // do some calculations
}
```

And this ?

```js
for await (const res of items.map(e => somethingAsync(e))) {
  // do some calculations
}
```

I know that in the first snippet, all the promises are fired at the same time but I'm not sure about the second. Does the for loop wait for the first iteration to be done to call the next promise ? Or are all the promises fired at the same time and the inside of the loop acts like a callback for them ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, they absolutely are different. `for await` is supposed to be used with asynchronous iterators, not with arrays of pre-existing promises.

Just to make clear,

```
for await (const res of items.map(e => somethingAsync(e))) …
```

works the same as

```
const promises = items.map(e => somethingAsync(e));
for await (const res of promises) …
```

or

```
const promises = [somethingAsync(items[0]), somethingAsync(items[1]), …];
for await (const res of promises) …
```

The `somethingAsync` calls are happening immediately, all at once, before anything is awaited. Then, they are `await`ed one after another, which is definitely a problem if any one of them gets rejected: it will cause an unhandled promise rejection error. **Using `Promise.all` is the only viable choice to deal with the array of promises**:

```
for (const res of await Promise.all(promises)) …
```

See [Waiting for more than one concurrent await operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) and [Any difference between await Promise.all() and multiple await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await) for details.

Comment: IMO an array of promises is assimilated to an asynchronous iterator as they yield the control back to the event loop, right ? What if, in my `somethingAsync` function, I catch everything correctly ?

Comment: Yes, the array is providing an asynchronous iterator, that's why the loop doesn't throw a protocol error. But that iteration is awaiting one promise at a time, ignoring errors from promises later in the array. Sure, if `somethingAsync` never errors, nothing bad will happen, but that's hard to guarantee. Using `for await` on an array of promises is still a bad practice.

Comment: Ok, will use `Promise.all` , thanks for your clarifications

Comment: So basically, Promise.all executes the promise in paralell whereas for await executes them in series. Am I right?

Comment: @VigneshM No, neither `Promise.all` nor `for await` "execute" anything. The  `somethingAction` calls that create the promises are made beforehand, all at once, without any waiting, and the actions will run concurrently. `for await` is wrong, `Promise.all` is the only correct way to deal with this situation where you have multiple promises that you need to wait for. If you wanted sequential execution, you'd need to do `for (const e of items) { const res = await somethingAsync(e); … }`, with the `await` in the loop body.

Answer (score 29):

The need for `for await ...` arises when on an asynchronous iterator the computation of the current  iteration depends on some of the previous iterations. If there are no dependences, `Promise.all` is your choice. The `for await` construct was designed to work with asynchronous iterators, although - as in your example, you can use it with an array of promises.

See the example [paginated data](https://javascript.info/async-iterators-generators#real-life-example-paginated-data) in the book [javascript.info](https://javascript.info) for an example using an asynchronous iterator that can't be rewritten using `Promise.all`:

```js
(async () => {
  for await (const commit of fetchCommits('javascript-tutorial/en.javascript.info')) {
    console.log(commit.author.login);
  }
})();
```

Here the `fetchCommits` async iterator makes a request to `fetch` the commits of a GitHub repo. The `fetch` responds with a JSON of 30 commits, and also provides a link to the next page in the `Link` header. **Therefore the next iteration can only start after the previous iteration has the link for the next request**

```js
async function* fetchCommits(repo) {
  let url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/commits`;

  while (url) {
    const response = await fetch(url, { 
      headers: {'User-Agent': 'Our script'}, 
    });

    const body = await response.json(); // (array of commits

    // The URL of the next page is in the headers, extract it using a regexp
    let nextPage = response.headers.get('Link').match(/<(.*?)>; rel="next"/);
    nextPage = nextPage?.[1];

    url = nextPage;

    for(let commit of body) { // yield commits one by one, until the page ends
      yield commit;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very clear, thanks. In your code samples, `for await` behaves like `yield*` isn't it ? Because you yield multiple items per iteration

Comment: There is no generator composition, just a `yield` per commit. After every 30 iterations a new page is loaded, and the next 30 commits are `yield`ed. Really **the dependence between iterations only happens every thirty times**.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for providing an actually useful demonstration of generator functions.  Every other example I've ever seen of them was contrived, and did not provide any good reason to actually use them.  This is the best example I've ever seen, and now I completely understand why one would use them.  Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

As you said `Promise.all` will send all the requests in one go and then you will get the response when all of them gets completed.

In the second scenario, you will send the request in one go but recieve response as for each one by one.

See this small example for reference.

```js
let i = 1;
function somethingAsync(time) {
  console.log("fired");
  return delay(time).then(() => Promise.resolve(i++));
}
const items = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000];

function delay(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { 
      setTimeout(resolve, time)
  });
}

(async() => {
  console.time("first way");
  const promises = await Promise.all(items.map(e => somethingAsync(e)));
  for (const res of promises) {
    console.log(res);
  }
  console.timeEnd("first way");

  i=1; //reset counter
  console.time("second way");
  for await (const res of items.map(e => somethingAsync(e))) {
    // do some calculations
    console.log(res);
  }
  console.timeEnd("second way");
})();
```

You could try it here as well - https://repl.it/repls/SuddenUselessAnalyst

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact you proved my second point. Using `for await` actually fires all the promises at the same time, hence the execution time for the loop: 4 seconds. If it waited for one to finish to go next, total execution time would have been 1+2+3+4 = 10 secs.

Comment: that's true. added the time part to prove that.

Comment: so in simple words, promise.all = wait once and for await = wait everytime?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, using the `for await` syntax does fire the promises all at once.

The small piece of code proves it:

```js
const sleep = s => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, s * 1000);
  });
}

const somethingAsync = async t => {
  await sleep(t);
  return t;
}

(async () => {
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  const now = Date.now();
  for await (const res of items.map(e => somethingAsync(e))) {
    console.log(res);
  }
  console.log("time: ", (Date.now() - now) / 1000);
})();
```

stdout:
`time:  4.001`

But the inside of the loop doesn't act "as a callback". If I reverse the array, all the logs appear at once. I suppose that the promises are fired at once and the runtime just waits for the first one to resolve to go to the next iteration.

EDIT: Actually, using `for await` is bad practice when we use it with something other than an asynchronous iterator, best is to use `Promise.all`, according to @Bergi in his answer.