# Access current iteration (index) during for await of loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, async-await

### There is a question about `for await ... of` loop.

I have the following code:

```
    for await (let V of reagentItems.map(objectElement => getPricing(objectElement))) {
       console.log(objectElement) //I'd like to have access to the current iteration.
       //or
       console.log(reagentItems[i]) //current fulfilled element from reagent.map
    }
```

So the problem is that this array (from `.map`) of functions (V as a single response of `getPricing`) doesn't return the `objectElement` itself but I need to have access to this `objectElement` inside `for await ... of` loop.

> Does it possible somehow or not? And if it doesn't, using of `Promise.all` handles this problem somehow? Or I should modify the original `getPricing` and `return` current `objectElement` with other results?

Comment: I'd recommend you split the question into the actual two questions it contains.

Comment: What exactly does `getPricing` return? A Promise?

Comment: an object like {item_id: Number, price: Number, ... } but this data from this object received via `async/await` functions, and `getPricing` doesn't return the `object_element` itself. So the question is all about: «Can I access the current_executed element/index from `Array` of functions»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [should not be using `for await` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695815/1048572) at all - that is meant for asynchronous generators. Instead, do

```
for (const object_element of reagent_items) {
    const V = await getPricing(object_element);
    console.log(object_element, V)
    …
}
```

With `Promise.all`, the code would look like this:

```
Promise.all(reagent_items.map(object_element =>
    getPricing(object_element).then(V => {
        console.log(object_element, V);
        …
    })
)).then(…)

// or:

await Promise.all(reagent_items.map(async object_element => {
    const V = await getPricing(object_element)
    console.log(object_element, V);
    …
}));
```

Comment: And what should I do, if I haven't option to request `getPricing` one-by-one, because `reagent_items` could consist 30+ reagents, which will lead to 30s execution instead of 30 parallel requests, executed in 1s?

Comment: @AlexZeDim for concurrent requests, use `Promise.all`

Comment: Well, yeah you right, `Promise.all` would be perfect solution here, because I can chain the result.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand from your question and your comments, you want to be able to access both `object_element` and the result of `getPricing(object_element)` within the `for` loop.

Your problem right now is that as a result of `map`, you only have the result of `getPricing`, but not the original `object_element`. As a solution, simply return both from `map` in an object:

```js
// just a random getPricing function
function getPricing(objectElement) {
    return {
        item_id: objectElement.id,
        price: Math.random()
    };
}

const reagent_items = [
    {
        id: 'a'
    },
    {
        id: 'b'
    }
];

for (let V of reagent_items.map(object_element => ({object_element, pricing: getPricing(object_element)}))) {
    console.log(`object_element: ${JSON.stringify(V.object_element)}, pricing: ${JSON.stringify(V.pricing)}`);
}
```

Comment: Seems that I should combine `.map` method with `Promise.all` as @Bergi mentioned above, but I also grateful to you, for noticing the question format and provided answer.