# How differently does our await keyword behave inside the for await of loop than in a normal async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, scheduled-tasks

Here's a simple async function:

```
async function f(){

    let data = await (new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000, 200)));
    
    console.log(data)
     
    return data + 100;   
}

f()

console.log('me first');
```

Here's what's going to happen in this program:

1. f() will be invoked
2. It goes inside f execution context and await expression is run - since function call has higher priority than await keyword, our new Promise() function will be run first which will return a pending promise right now and after that await keyword will work.
3. We set up a timer that will resolve our promise after 1 second
4. since its not yet resolved, await will return us a pending promise and we go one layer out of our current execution context which happens to be global execution context where we start executing global codes.
5. we hit "console.log('me first')" line and logs "me first"
6. now after 1second, our promise has been resolved which means all the code followed by our await expression will be put inside a container and put into the microtask queue for the execution in the next tick! (Under the hood it probably calls .next()  method just like a generator function but let's not go into that)
7. Our sync code is done and there's one task into our microtask queue, we put that into our call stack to run!
8. That runs and as soon as we go back into our async function, it starts from where it left i.e. the await expression.
9. since our promise is now resolved, our await keyword will extract the value from that resolved promise  and assign it to the variable d.
10. We log that value into the next line.
11. Finally, in the last line, we return the value + 100 from our async function which means the pending promise that we returned earlier (as mentioned in line 4) is resolved with that value i.e. 300!

So as you can see, I'm pretty comfortable with async await at this point!
Now here's the code we have with for await of iteration!

```
    async function f(){

        
        let p1 = new Promise(function (r){
            setTimeout(r, 2000, 1)
        })
        let p2 = new Promise(function (r){
            setTimeout(r, 1000, 2)
        })
        let p3 = new Promise(function (r){
            setTimeout(r, 500, 3)
        })
     
        let aop = [p1, p2, p3];
        
        for await (let elem of aop ){
            
            let data = await elem;
            console.log(data)
        }
        
    }    

f()
    
    console.log('global');
```

Now intuitively, you would expect this to happen assuming the await will behave the same as it did inside our previous async function!

1. f() is called
2. We create three promises p1, p2, p3
3. p1 will resolve after 2 second, p2 after 1 second and p3 after 500 m/s
4. We put these promises inside an array  called aop (because for of works with an object that has Symbol.iterator as the property and all array has that.)
5. Now this is where things feel tricky to me!
6. We'll iterate over each elements, for the first one, we go inside the loop and immediately await our first element, i.e. our first promise, p1.
7. Since it's not resolved yet, it returns us a pending promise like it did in our previous example, OR DOES IT?
8. The same will happen for other two promise, p2 and p3, more two pending promises are returned.
9. Our async function is finished, we go one layer outside into our global execution to this line which prints global: console.log('global');
10. At this point, our p3 promise has been resolved, since it was supposed to take only 500ms to finish, it resolved first! NOW THEN! Maybe whatever code we have left after that (console.log(data)) will be put into the microtask queue for later execution?
11. By this logic, it should print 3 since our last promise resolved first, then 2 and then 1 but its printing 1, 2, 3!
    So what crucial points have I missed in my writing?
    for await is obviously parallel so it'll go thru each elements without waiting for the first one to finish, so why is it working like that ?

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: You're saying "500ms" but your code says "5000" ms.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Oops, I've just edited! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I just laughed out loud after finding a discussion where I said "people will be surprised by this behaviour" from 5 years ago when we've made that decision :D

Comment: I repeat what I wrote on your previous question: [Never use for await with an array of promises!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694309/for-await-of-vs-promise-all)

Comment: @Bergi - Hey, yeah practically I wont be doing this, but I wanna know what happens when i do this way! Wont the 2nd iteration begin  until the first promise inside the first iteration is fulfilled? And if so, doesnt that make our code blocking in a way ?

Comment: @imheretolearn1 No, `[p1, p2, p3]` is not a stream of promises in the order in which they resolve, it's an array, and will be iterated sequentially. `for` loops don't skip elements or reorder them arbitrarily - and `for await` loops wait for each iterator step before advancing. No, this has nothing to do with blocking code, it's still asynchronous - notice the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

For await loops have special behaviour when you get a promise.

Remember - promises are **values** - once you have a promise the action creating that promise (in this case setting up the timer) has already occurred. The promise is just the value+time for that action.

What happens here is actually:

- You pass your array of promises (just results for already started actions) into `for...await`.
- Since that array has no `Symbol.asyncIterator` - the loop checks if it has a `Symbol.iterator`. Since arrays are iterable and have that symbol - it is invoked.
- The `for... await` loop checks for each returned value if it's a promise - if it is it waits for it before progressing the loop.

Since the values are promises - they will be ordered (that is, `.next()` will be called on the iterator returned from `[p1, p2, p3][Symbol.iterator]()` only after the previous promise returned from the previous `.next` call has settled.

---

Note:

- You are using `resolved` but mean `settled` or `fulfilled`.

Comment: If anyone cares - this particular design choice (awaiting the value on the consumer side) was a pretty interesting discussion and I'm happy to dig it up

Comment: Actually re-reading your question I think the behaviour you're confused by is only the fact `for...await` will await promises passed to it by the iterator?

Comment: Funny quote: " I imagine that, if we decide the other way, many will be surprised that " - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/15

Comment: Also more historical context about this exact behaviour: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration/issues/15#issuecomment-247768427

Comment: I think the thing that confuses me is why if we've gotten our last promise resloved, it still prints first promise first. I heard it doesnt wait for every promises to resolve unlike Promise.all

Comment: @imheretolearn1 think of it like a regular `for... of` loop except it checks if each value it received is a promise and if it is it `await`s it (on the consumer side)

Comment: "except it checks if each value it received is a promise and if it is it awaits" 

I see, but isnt while using for await of, we always await a promise anyways? 

Also just to be precise, do you mean if the first promise is not resolved, it wont go to the second iteration? if so, this will also mean for await of is non blocking because its not parallel then. 


(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: "Also just to be precise, do you mean if the first promise is not resolved, it wont go to the second iteration?" - yes. " if so, this will also mean for await of is non blocking because its not parallel then. (Sorry for my bad English) " - blocking isn't the right term, and you probably mean concurrency rather than parallelism - but "yes" - for await (and for loops in general) are sequential by design.

Comment: Also you should apologize for less-than-perfect English. A lot of the people writing this stuff have less-than-perfect English and it doesn't prevent them from creating a ton of value and actually writing the features you and me are using. Heck. I'm ESL myself :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this was confusing me so much and I'm much comfortable now! :)

Comment: Btw, what if we are not awaiting our promises? Will the for await of iterate over every element synchronously then?

Comment: No, `for await` will unwrap the promises. Read the thread I linked to :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't talk to the specific implementations of jobs in each engine (or even polyfills) but creating promises shouldn't push code into a separate stack. The `await` mechanism should do it.

Since we are talking about a regular iterable. The code shouldn't be that much different from:

```
console.log(await p1);
console.log(await p2);
console.log(await p3);
```

Precise semantics, are of course, not exactly the same. Order is still guaranteed by the iterator which is the main point. Even if `p3` resolves first, the value is retrieved after it's awaited which happens after `p2` and `p1` are awaited.

Technically, each value that is a promise is being `await`ed with `for await(... of ...)` so, `await`ing the value of the binding does nothing really (other than maybe pushing further code into the next stack).

E.g. you have `console.log(await await p1);`

Comment: Actually semantics are very very close to that :-)