# Node throws unhandled promise rejection while using rejected promise as input parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, unhandled-promise-rejection

I discovered a weird issue while trying to implement a function that awaits all promises of an array and catches all errors. This implementation led to a complete application crash caused by an unhandled promise rejection.

```js
const completeAllPromises = async (promises) => {
    const errors = []

    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        await promises[i].catch((error) => {
            error.message = `${i}: ${error.message}`
            errors.push(error)
        })
    }

    if (errors.length) return Promise.reject(errors)
}

const timeout = (duration) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve()), duration)
}

const fail = async () => {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Failed'))
}

const crash = async () => {
    await completeAllPromises([timeout(100), fail()]).catch(
        (error) => console.log(`Crash prevented, catch promise rejection`, error), // never be called
    )
}

const main = async () => {
    // will crash and catch will not be called
    await crash().catch((error) => console.log('Finished crash() and catch error', error))
}

main()
```

It seems like the catch implementation in `completeAllPromises` function is executed at runtime, so while awaiting the first timeout promise, `fail()` will reject and not be catch. The weird thing for me is that the `crash()` and also not `main()` will catch this error. It almost seems like the call chain is not resolvable at the time `fail()` rejects.

Switching `timeout(100)` and `fail()` will result in a properly catch errors. Using a try and catch block will also lead to the same issue.

### Solution ✅

```js
const completeAllPromises = async (promises) => {
    const errors = []
    const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
    results.forEach((result) => {
        if (result.status === 'rejected') errors.push(result.reason)
    })
    if (errors.length) return Promise.reject(errors)
}

const timeout = (duration) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve()), duration)
}

const fail = async () => {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('Failed'))
}

const crash = async () => {
    await completeAllPromises([timeout(100), fail()]).catch(
        (error) => console.log(`Crash prevented, catch promise rejection`, error), // never be called
    )
}

const main = async () => {
    // will crash and catch will not be called
    await crash().catch((error) => console.log('Finished crash() and catch error', error))
}

main()
```

Comment: why dont you use allSettled (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) instead ?

Comment: "*runs an array of promises*" doesn't make sense. Promises cannot be executed, they can only be observed. As soon as you call `timeout(100)` and `fail()`, the asynchronous tasks are already running - before you pass anything to `completeAllPromises`.

Comment: See 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await for why you get the unhandled promise rejection. Maybe also https://stackoverflow.com/q/59694309/1048572

Comment: It's **really** subtle, but it is fundamentally the issue Bergi points to above. Here's how it happens: You call `timeout` and `fail` and pass the resulting promises into `completeAllPromises`. That function starts a loop, calls `catch` on the promise from `timeout`, and awaits the result. At that point, nothing is handling rejection of the promise from `fail`, and the stack unwinds (waiting for the timeout) and returns to platform code (Node.js's internal event loop code). The platform code sees that `fail`'s promise has been rejected and the rejection has not been caught (yet). You could...

Comment: ...fix it by removing the `await` in the loop and instead storing the promises you get from `catch` in an array, then `await Promise.all(thatArray)` before doing your `return`. But as @JiaSH pointed out, there's already a tool for this: `Promise.allSettled`.

Comment: (I should have said above: You **do** end up handling the rejection from `fail`, it's just that you don't do it before the unhandled rejection detection kicks in, because you don't do it until after you `await` the `timeout` promise.)

Comment: Separately: I **strongly** urge you not to combine `async`/`await` syntax with `.catch` method calls, it's really hard to read. If you want to catch promise rejection in an `async` function, use `try`/`catch` around the `await` instead (or an existing promise combinator like `Promise.allSettled`).