# javascript - promise handling between for-loop and map()

Tags: javascript, promise

using for-loop

```
    let arr=[]
    for (let mkt of markets) {
      const resA = await someAsyncFuncA(context, mkt[0].serumMarket);
      const resB = await someAsyncFuncB(resA);
      console.log(resB) 
      arr.push(resB)
    }
    console.log(arr) // it will log after the for-loop complete
```

But when I am using `map()`.

```
    let arr = [];
     markets.map(async (mkt) => {
      const resA = await someAsyncFuncA(context, mkt[0].serumMarket);
      const resB = await someAsyncFuncB(resA);
      console.log(resB) // it will log after console.log(arr) below
      arr.push(resB)
    });
    console.log(arr) // it will log first: []
```

I want to understand more for these 2 kinds of loop, such as the performance.
It seems `map()` always executes faster than `for-loop`, should I always use `map()`?
When should I use `for-loop`?

Comment: `map` doesn't waits for promises to settle, that is why the last `console.log` statement executes early.

Comment: It doesn’t “execute faster”. This is unrelated to performance. `await` stops execution of the current function until a Promise is resolved. In the first snippet `console.log(arr)` is included in the current function, in the second snippet it isn’t.

Comment: `await` inside a loop when you want to run them serially. If in parallel, use `Promise.all` and `.map`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695815/13658816) provide some relevant info? It is not comparing `for ... of` with `.map` but still provides useful info, I think.

Comment: This [blog](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/map-vs-for-loop-2b4ce659fb03) describes **map vs. for loop**