# Test multiple parsing outputs instead of hardcoding each of them into a constant Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So in my application I am cron parsing multiple database data and I have it right now to where I create a const run for each data to find the dag_id and test the determineCron one at a time manually. How would I make an array so that the "determineCron()" at the bottom will test every run instead of me just manually coding determineCron(run), determineCron(run2), determineCron(run3), determineCron(run4) etc.

```js
const run = {
    start_date: '2022-07-01T13:45:01.221636+00:00',
        end_date: '2022-07-01T14:11:01.864293+00:00',
    state: 'success',
    dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-30T13:45:00+00:00',
    dag_id: 'IPP_CYCLE_PARMS',
}

const run2 = {
    start_date: '2022-06-26T23:00:00.742495+00:00',
    end_date: '2022-06-27T14:10:23.108401+00:00',
    state: 'failed',
    dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-25T23:00:00+00:00',
    dag_id: 'EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch'
}

async function determineCron(result){
    /*dagID = result?.[0]?.dag_id || 0*/
    dagID = result ? result.dag_id : 0
    console.log(dagID)
    job = await bqConnection().query(`SELECT * FROM \`np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.expected_sla\` where dag_id = "${dagID}"`)
    console.log(job[0][0]);
    cronTime = job[0][0].cron_time
    var interval = parser.parseExpression(cronTime);
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
}
determineCron(run)
determineCron(run2)
```

Comment: In addition I have the cronTime as job[0][0], if there is a way to make an array to loop through each run that would be good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array with the references of the constants, but it's tricky after that, because if you use any built-in array method like map, forEach, reduce... to execute the function it will not await the previous finish to execute the next call. Therefore, what you should do is to use [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and their respective variations..

```
// if you are in a async scope you can remove that self invoked function

(async function () {
  const runs = [
    {
      start_date: "2022-07-01T13:45:01.221636+00:00",
      end_date: "2022-07-01T14:11:01.864293+00:00",
      state: "success",
      dag_run_id: "scheduled__2022-06-30T13:45:00+00:00",
      dag_id: "IPP_CYCLE_PARMS",
    },
    {
      start_date: "2022-06-26T23:00:00.742495+00:00",
      end_date: "2022-06-27T14:10:23.108401+00:00",
      state: "failed",
      dag_run_id: "scheduled__2022-06-25T23:00:00+00:00",
      dag_id: "EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch",
    },
  ];

  async function determineCron(result) {
    /*dagID = result?.[0]?.dag_id || 0*/
    dagID = result ? result.dag_id : 0;
    console.log(dagID);
    job = await bqConnection().query(
      `SELECT * FROM \`np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.expected_sla\` where dag_id = "${dagID}"`
    );
    console.log(job[0][0]);
    cronTime = job[0][0].cron_time;
    var interval = parser.parseExpression(cronTime);
    console.log("Date: ", interval.next().toString());
  }

  for (let run of runs) {
    await determineCron(run);
  }
})();
```

Comment: cronTime = job[0][0].cron_time
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cron_time')

Comment: So I am getting this error with the job[0][0] do you know by any chance on how i would change this. cron_time is a field in that bigquery table (expected_sla)

Comment: What is the log of console.log(job[0][0])? If you're using the self invoked function, you need to encapsulate all your code inside it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that array.forEach(await f) doesn't work! I hadn't known that.

Comment: {
  dag_id: 'oclt-leadtime-daily',
  cron_time: '00 23 * * 1-6',
  expected_end_time: '23:10:00'
}

Comment: this is an example of what job[0][0] log outputs so I have a total of 12 different data and after the 11th run it outputs an error for the job[0][0] and I am not sure. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Never mind it looks like i did not add that to the bigquery thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
const runs = [
{
    start_date: '2022-07-01T13:45:01.221636+00:00',
        end_date: '2022-07-01T14:11:01.864293+00:00',
    state: 'success',
    dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-30T13:45:00+00:00',
    dag_id: 'IPP_CYCLE_PARMS',
},
{
    start_date: '2022-06-26T23:00:00.742495+00:00',
    end_date: '2022-06-27T14:10:23.108401+00:00',
    state: 'failed',
    dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-25T23:00:00+00:00',
    dag_id: 'EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch'
}
]
runs.forEach(determineCron)
```

Comment: Hi, so how would i test each of the parsed data in the determineCron function that would just test the runs data

Comment: it is giving me an error  throw new Error('Validation error, cannot resolve alias "' + match + '"');

Answer (score 0):

Put your runs into an array and then use array.forEach, like this:

```js
interface CronRun {
  start_date: string;
  end_date: string;
  state: string;
  dag_run_id: string;
  dag_id: string;
}

const runs: CronRun[] = [
  {
    start_date: '2022-07-01T13:45:01.221636+00:00',
    end_date: '2022-07-01T14:11:01.864293+00:00',
    state: 'success',
    dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-30T13:45:00+00:00',
    dag_id: 'IPP_CYCLE_PARMS',
  },
  {
    start_date: '2022-06-26T23:00:00.742495+00:00',
    end_date: '2022-06-27T14:10:23.108401+00:00',
    state: 'failed',
    dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-25T23:00:00+00:00',
    dag_id: 'EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch'
  }
];

async function determineCron(result: ChronRun){
    /*dagID = result?.[0]?.dag_id || 0*/
    dagID = result ? result.dag_id : 0
    console.log(dagID)
    job = await bqConnection().query(`SELECT * FROM \`np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.expected_sla\` where dag_id = "${dagID}"`)
    console.log(job[0][0]);
    cronTime = job[0][0].cron_time
    var interval = parser.parseExpression(cronTime);
    console.log('Date: ', interval.next().toString());
}

runs.forEach(determineCron);
```

like your original code, this will run them all in parallel. If you want them in serial you'll have to do

```
for (const run of runs) {
  await determineCron(run);
}
```

instead.

Comment: interface CronRun {
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 its giving this error for CronRun

Comment: interfaces should not be inside of classes. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes i believe so its saying thats its an unexpected identifier

Comment: Then move the interface declaration to it's own file and import it. Best practice is to do this anyway.

Comment: You have to use `for await (..) {...}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer Wait, are you sure? `(async function() { const nums = [500, 100, 2]; const delay = async function (ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)).then(() => console.log(ms));}; for (const ms of nums) { await delay(ms); }})()` prints out 500, 100, and 2 as expected.

Comment: Yes, positive. If you want to use await in a for of loop, use the for await version of it

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer, I played around more, looked more, and `for await` is only best for asynchronous iterators. See [//stackoverflow.com/a/59695815/7158380](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695815/7158380).

Comment: Yes of course, you'd use `for await` only if you have async function calls in your loop. It's the case in above example, see your `await determineCron(run);` If you "fire and forget", then you don't need it, but if you want the iteration of the loop to wait until your asnyc function actually returns something, you'd use `for await`

Comment: No. It's for asynchronous iterators, not a synchronous iterator that happens to return promises. `for (const ms of nums) { await delay(ms); }; console.log('fin');` prints "fin" last. `for await (const ms of nums) { delay(ms); }; console.log('fin');` does not. For me, anyway. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯