# How can I convert an array of Promises to an AsyncIterable (or a normal Iterable)?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that puts a bunch of async operations into an array and waits for them to resolve before continuing.

```js
function foo(reqs: () => Promise<string>): Promise<string[]> {
  const ops: Array<Promise<string>> = []

  for (const req of reqs) {
    ops.push(req())
  }

  return Promise.all(ops)
}
```

I would like to be notified when each promise resolves, regardless of order. I can do this easily with a callback.

```js
function foo(
  reqs: () => Promise<string>, 
  onResolved: (value: string) => any,
): Promise<string[]> {
  const ops: Array<Promise<string>> = []

  for (const req of reqs) {
    const f = async () => {
      const s = await req()
      onResolved(s)
      return s
    }
    ops.push(f())
  }

  return Promise.all(ops)
}
```

The async iterable syntax is interesting and I am wondering if this is the type of use case it's expected to handle.

Is it possible to use an async iterator for this so these events can be consumed as a for loop?

```js
for await (const req of foo(reqs)) {
  console.log(req)
}
```

Or due to back pressure issues, can a normal iterator be used for this where the loop runs in order of promise resolution?

```js
for (const req of foo(reqs)) {
  (async () => {
    console.log(await req)
  })()
}
```

Comment: "*I am wondering if this is the type of use case it's expected to handle.*" - no, it's not, precisely because of the backpressure issues. If the loop doesn't continue (because it's suspended, or even simply `break`ed out of), the remaining promises are left unhandled, which is bad.

Comment: Keep it simple: `await Promise.all(reqs.map(req => req().then(onResolved)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays of promises directly in `for...of` or `for await...of` loops will cause issues since even when wrapped in a `try...catch` block, only the first rejected promise will be caught and the rest will be unhandled.

The simplest way to deal with an array of promises is with `Promise.all` but if you need access to values as they resolve the following two functions can help.

```
// iterates in array order
async function* toAsyncIterable<T>(array: T[]) {
  Promise.all(array).catch(() => {})
  yield* array
}
```

```
// iterates in promise resolution order
async function* toRacingIterable<T>(array: T[]) {
  const promiseContainerMap = new Map(array.map(item => {
    const promise = Promise.resolve(item)
    return [promise, promise.then(value => [promise, value] as const)]
  }))
  while (promiseContainerMap.size) {
    const [key, value] = await Promise.race(promiseContainerMap.values())
    promiseContainerMap.delete(key)
    yield value
  }
}
```

Demos

```js
async function* toAsyncIterable(array) {
  Promise.all(array).catch(() => {})
  yield* array
}

const demo = async() => {
  const delay = (value, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms))

  const promises = [delay("A", 1000), delay("B", 3000), delay("C", 2000), "D"]

  for await (let item of toAsyncIterable(promises)) {
    console.log(item)
  }
}
demo()
```

```js
async function* toRacingIterable(array) {
  const promiseContainerMap = new Map(array.map(item => {
    const promise = Promise.resolve(item);
    return [promise, promise.then(value => [promise, value])];
  }));
  while (promiseContainerMap.size) {
    const [key, value] = await Promise.race(promiseContainerMap.values());
    promiseContainerMap.delete(key);
    yield value;
  }
}

const demo = async() => {
  const delay = (value, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms))

  const promises = [delay("A", 1000), delay("B", 3000), delay("C", 2000), "D"]

  for await (let item of toRacingIterable(promises)) {
    console.log(item)
  }
}
demo()
```

**Edit**: original answer was buggy as pointed out by @Bergi and has been rewritten accordingly

Comment: [You should **never** use `for await` with an array of promises!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59694309/1048572)

Comment: `promise.then(() => { pending.delete(promise) });` also causes unhandled promise rejections that will crash you app

Comment: Thank you @Bergi for pointing that out. I rewrote the answer to address your concerns

Comment: Thanks, that works! Though instead of using an array for a `promiseContainer`, and having it contain a promise that then again needs to be awaited, I'd probably write `const promise = Promise.resolve(item); const key = promise; return [key, promise.then(value => ({ key, value }))];` and `const { key, value } = await Promise.race(promiseMap.values()); promiseMap.delete(key); yield value;`. Using `const key = promise` works, but it could be anything else (like the `map()` index).

Comment: Good suggestion, I was hung up on having `Promise.race` return the key directly but that's not necessary