# Why Promise are eager, resolve itself before call await/then, instead of lazy

Tags: javascript

I have a method for execute an array of Promise in chunk.

```
function* chunkArrayPromiseGenerator(array, chunk) {
  let queue = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    queue.push(array[i]);
    if (queue.length >= chunk) {
      yield Promise.all(queue);
      queue = [];
    }
  }
  if (queue.length !== 0) {
    yield Promise.all(queue);
  }
}
```

This is just a fake async methd

```
let executedCount = 0;
const asyncTask = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  executedCount++;
  resolve(executedCount);
});
```

The expected behaviour: `chunkArrayPromiseGenerator()` execute the promises because await the result of `asyncTask()`, it works:

```
for await (const results of chunkArrayPromiseGenerator([asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask()], 2)){
   console.log(results); // [1, 2] [3, 4]
}
```

But doesn't works in this case, the expected result is 0 because no await the result! but is 4

```
executedCount = 0;
chunkArrayPromiseGenerator([asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask()], 2);
console.log(executedCount); // return 4
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` waits for all the promises in the list to resolve

Comment: @Pointy It doesn't wait by itself, it returns a promise that resolves when they all resolve. If you don't await it, it shouldn't wait.

Comment: @Pointy Also without await? `await Promise.all()`

Comment: The whole point of Promise.all() is to wait for the individual promises to all resolve.

Comment: @Barmar yes sorry, of course that's correct, but because that counter is updated as a side effect of the *creation* of the Promise instances, it doesn't matter whether they're awaited or not.

Comment: @Barman Promises are "eager", meaning they will happen whether no one is listening or not.

Comment: If promises aren't eager, there's hardly any point to them. The reason we run code asynchronously is so that we can do other things while it's processing. E.g. we send an AJAX request immediately, and do other things instead of waiting for the server response.

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694309/for-await-of-vs-promise-all

Comment: Also you initiate the function when you define your array. Try passing them in without parenthesis: ```chunkArrayPromiseGenerator([asyncTask, asyncTask, asyncTask, asyncTask]```

Answer (score 0):

Promises are "eager", meaning they will happen whether no one is listening or not.

According to MDN:

> The executor function is executed immediately by the Promise
> implementation, passing resolve and reject functions

If you're doing some heavy operations and would like to only do it when the promise is actually used, you need a custom lazy Promise, eg.:

```js
class LazyPromise extends Promise {
    #executor;
    #promise;

    constructor(executor) {
        super(resolve => {
            resolve();
        });
        this.#executor = executor;
    }

    static from(callback) {
        return new LazyPromise(resolve => {
            resolve(callback());
        });
    }

    static resolve(value) {
        return new LazyPromise(resolve => {
            resolve(value);
        });
    }

    static reject(error) {
        return new LazyPromise((resolve, reject) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    }

    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        this.#promise = this.#promise || new Promise(this.#executor);
        return this.#promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }

    catch(onRejected) {
        this.#promise = this.#promise || new Promise(this.#executor);
        return this.#promise.catch(onRejected);
    }
}

function* chunkArrayPromiseGenerator(array, chunk) {
      let queue = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          queue.push(array[i]);
          if (queue.length >= chunk) {
            yield Promise.all(queue);
            queue = [];
          }
      }
      if (queue.length !== 0) {
          yield Promise.all(queue);
      }
}

let executedCount = 0;
const asyncTask = () => new LazyPromise(resolve => {
    executedCount++;
    resolve(executedCount);
});

(async () => {

    for await (const results of chunkArrayPromiseGenerator([asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask()], 2)){
       console.log(results); // [1, 2] [3, 4]
    }
    console.log('executedCount', executedCount); // expected 4

    executedCount = 0;
    const generator = chunkArrayPromiseGenerator([asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask(), asyncTask()], 2);
    console.log('executedCount', executedCount); // expected 0 because no await
    
    for await (const results of generator){
       console.log(results); // [1, 2] [3, 4]
    }
    console.log('executedCount', executedCount); // expected 4

})();
```