# Is array.forEach(callback) with async/await inside each iteration asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, frontend

I am working with react and I have the following code:

```
    const [avatarURLs, setAvatarURLs] = useState({});
    const [currentTutorProfile, setCurrentTutorProfile] = useState({});
    const [avatarURLsLoaded, setAvatarURLsLoaded] = useState(false); // New state

    useEffect(() => {
        const avatarObject = {};
        const fetchAvatar = async (tutorProfile) => {
            try {
                if (tutorProfile) {
                    const response = await axios.get(
                        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/users/${tutorProfile.owner}/avatar`,
                        { responseType: "arraybuffer" }
                    );
                    const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
                        type: "image/png",
                    });
                    const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    avatarObject[tutorProfile.owner] = "imageUrl";
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // console.error("Error fetching user avatar:", error);
            }
        };
        tutorProfilesArray.forEach(fetchAvatar);
        console.log(avatarObject); // THIS ONE

        setAvatarURLs(avatarObject);
        setAvatarURLsLoaded(true); // Mark that avatarURLs are loaded
    }, [tutorProfilesArray]);
```

I have a console.log(avatarObject) // THIS ONE, line that tests the avatarObject and I get empty objects and then the objects values get filled after some time.

[empty objects then filled after some time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir3hb.png)

I noticed that this behavior was only present when the api call is used with await (ex: await axios.get()). When the api call is used without the await (ex: axios.get()), the avatarObject was updated immediately. So here are what I don't understand; Since await is used, shouldn't the line be executed in a sequential (synchronous) way even the api calls are done?

This is my side project that I have been working on for months and I have been struggling to solve this issue for a week and could not figure out why and how to fix this issue. If this happens to be something you might know the solution to, I would greatly appreciate if I could hear some explanations.

Thank you

What I was trying was this: loop over an array and fetch profile picture for each element of the array and using an object store it to a react useState variable.

Problem: It did store profile pictures to the useState variable but, it was done after some time (I assume) so that when the frontend gets rendered initially, it does not see any profile pictures so it renders no profile pictures.

Comment: `array.forEach` with an asynchronous function rarely does what you actually want - unless what you want is absolutely no results from the callback function to be available at a known point in subsequent code ... i.e. yes, async functions remain asynchronous even inside a `.forEach`

Comment: "*When the api call is used without the await (ex: axios.get()), the avatarObject was updated immediately*" - well sure, but it would be updated with the wrong value, as `response` would have been a promise and `response.data` would have been undefined.

Comment: @JaromandaX I see, will keep that in mind writing JS onward, thanks!

Comment: @Bergi You are right, that explains why it "seemed" like it was updated immediately without the await. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. In fact, the callback inside the `.forEach` can be asynchronous, but the `forEach` statement itself can not. This means that the `console.log(avatarObject);` will be executed while the callbacks inside the `forEach` statement are still being processed. This is why at first you see an empty object, but after some time you see the object filled.

There are some ways to work around this:

### 1. Using `Promise.all` with `map`

The `map` method works like the `forEach` method, but the difference is that it returns a new array with the result of each callback executed, which in case of an asynchronous callback the result will be a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Given that, you can use the `Promise.all` statement to wait for all the callbacks inside the `map` to be finalized before going forward. Like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchUsersAvatarAndUpdateState() {
    const avatarObject = {};

    await Promise.all(
      tutorProfilesArray.map(async (tutorProfile) => {
        // ... code
      }),
    );
    console.log(avatarObject); // THIS ONE

    setAvatarURLs(avatarObject);
    setAvatarURLsLoaded(true); // Mark that avatarURLs are loaded
  }

  fetchUsersAvatarAndUpdateState();
}, [tutorProfilesArray]);
```

### 2. Use `for await` instead

The `for await (...)` loop is asynchronous and can be used for asynchronous iterations, like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchUsersAvatarAndUpdateState() {
    const avatarObject = {};

    for await (const tutorProfile of tutorProfilesArray) {
      // ... code
    }
    console.log(avatarObject); // THIS ONE

    setAvatarURLs(avatarObject);
    setAvatarURLsLoaded(true); // Mark that avatarURLs are loaded
  }

  fetchUsersAvatarAndUpdateState();
}, [tutorProfilesArray]);
```

> Note that there are some differences between those two solutions. If you want to go deeper on that, I suggest reading this thread: [for await of VS Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694309/for-await-of-vs-promise-all)

Comment: Covered by a long standing duplicate